# How to detect link from tweets in ios native app

Tags: ios, objective-c, tweets

I am showing tweets in an iOS native app. I am showing the tweets on the `UILabel` in a `UITableView`.

I want user able to click on the link that are part of tweet text.

But the links in tweet text are not prefix by `http://` or `www`. Instead, the link contains `@` and `#` as prefix.

I used `UITextView` with `datadetector` type property but not able to detect link.
I read some article that the UIWebView can be use to detect link; but I don't think I should use `UIWebView` in `UITableView` cell.

Is there any way to achieve this in iOS? My app supports iOS 5+.

Comment: It's quite complex for previous than iOS7 that can get (NSLinkAttribute for UILabel). You should do it with manually getting references of links, detect tap, etc. A few discussion on StackOverFlow discuss about that with UITextView.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing provided by the SDK that will do this out of the box, but the necessary pieces are there to build your own `UILabel` subclass that will handle this kind of data detection. If that's not something you want to take on, take a look at [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel).